# Регулярка для поиска id vk в тексте

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

**Текст:** `https://vk.com/id1`

Нужно в тексте выделить id 'единицу'

**Текст:** `https://vk.com/id33`

Будет 33

Comment: 100 рублей :) /vk\.com\/id(\d+)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для написания регулярных выражений можно использовать онлайн конструкторы, например http://uvsoftium.ru/php/regexp.php

Там имеется подробная справка по написанию.

В вашем случае имеет вид:    `vk\.com\/id(\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
/https?:\/\/vk\.com\/id(-?\d+)/
```

А возможно так:

```
/https?:\/\/vk\.com\/(?:id)?(-?\w+)/
```

Comment: Отрицательного числа быть не может.

Comment: @andreymal, у групп же отрицательные id.

Comment: Адреса групп начинаются с club, public и event, но не с id. И минуса всё равно не содержат, кстати

Comment: @andreymal, хм.. посмотрел. Минус появляется в аудио и видео списках групп.

Comment: Вот там бывает, да. И в фотографиях и на стене. Но не с id)

Answer (score 0):

Пример на php:

```
$vk_url = "https://vk.com/id33";

$string = preg_replace("/https?:\/\/vk\.com\/id/", '', $vk_url);
```

---

> Как пример без запроса к VK API, но лучше проверять через VK API что-бы убрать случаи когда `screen_name` начинается с `id`

Но в сейчас очень часто используют `screen_name` и нужна проверка это `id` или `screen_name` и уже учитывая это строить запрос к API и проверять, и записывать либо id либо цифры:

```
$vk_url = "https://vk.com/id33";

$string = preg_replace("/https?:\/\/vk\.com\/(id:?)?/", '', $vk_url);
```